# NextJs generate PDF via API route

Tags: node.js, next.js, serverless, vercel

I am using nextjs `13.0.6` with supabase. The task I want to accomplish is to generate and download a PDF file. Therefore I have developed an endpoint which generates the PDF via nextjs api routes. This generated file gets temporarily stored and uploaded to supabase. At the end the Endpoint should return the PDF, so I am able also download it within the browser.

My problem is that the code below **works flawlessly on local environment**, but as soon I upload it to `vercel` the generated PDF is 'broken' and will not open, neither by downloading from the browser nor downloading it from the supabase bucket.

Digging into the `logs` on vercel I could identify that something went's wrong as I am getting this message:

```
RequestInit: duplex option is required when sending a body.
```

**/pages/api/pdf_generate.ts**

```
export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {

  // Generate PDF
  const pdf_stream = await createAllocationPDF(data)

  // Upload to bucket
  await supabase.storage
    .from('files')
    .upload(`/pdf/allocations/Allocation_${data[0].allocations_id}.pdf`, pdf_stream)

  // Return PDF from tmp folder
  // we need this because after uploading to supabase storage the previous stream gets closed
  const pdf = fs.readFileSync(getPDFFilePath(data[0].allocation))

  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
  res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=Allocation.pdf')
  return res.status(200).send(pdf)
}
```

**Frontend implementation for downloading**

```
export async function downloadAllocationPDF(allocationId: number): Promise<void> {
  const request = new Request(`/api/pdf_generate?id=${allocationId}`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
      Accept: 'application/pdf'
    },
    // @ts-ignore
    duplex: 'half' // DIDN'T WORK
  })
  const res = await fetch(request)
  const blob = await res.blob()
  const blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  const tempLink = document.createElement('a')
  tempLink.href = blobUrl
  tempLink.setAttribute('download', `Allocation_${allocationId}.pdf`)
  tempLink.click()
}
```

Comment: What library are you using for generate the pdf?